# Next self referencing loop json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

When signalr sends a response to the client sometimes there is a self referencing loop. How can I fix this in MVC5?

In a normal ASP.NET mvc 5 project I used:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;     
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling 
     = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

How can I do this in a ASP.NET mvc 6 Vnext project?

Answer (score 1):

Core changes in current builder:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/9d89a8cac3cb5fb6b1aa7138814957708c2c22ca

```
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; ;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {

        var jsonFormatter = options.OutputFormatters
            .OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>()
            .First();

        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue using the code below.

```
services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
    var jsonFormatter = (JsonOutputFormatter)options.OutputFormatters
    .Where(o => o.Instance.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter)).First().Instance;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
         ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

});
```